# Unable to use aircrack-ng commands after using the argument --bssid with airodump-ng!

Tags: pi-4, linux, kali

I'm using the internal network adapter which comes with the Raspberry Pi 4 and Kali OS's Pi 4.
First I type the command

`airmon-ng check kill`

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAoNQ.jpg)

`airmon-ng start wlan0`

Then `airodump-ng wlan0mon`

[Notice there is no text on the right side of 05:28.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Z2n.jpg)

After running
`airodump-ng --bssid 08:25:25:xx:xx --channel 11` for an average 8 seconds the command stops working that is #Data column does'nt increase. Similarly the commands `airodump-ng wlan0mon` and other commands of the suite also don't work.

[Fixed channel wlan0mon -1 on top right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Ags.jpg)

[The actual problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qthwm.png)

I've tried using `airmon-ng check kill` after that which doesn't give any output like it does usually.
`ifconfig wlan0 down` and `ifconfig wlan0mon down` and then `ifconfig wlan0 up` and `ifconfig wlan0mon up` does'nt seem to help.

Does anyone know what is happening here? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you have example of console input/output, please don't post is as screenshots (or in your case, link externally), but copy-and-paste it into your question with proper formatting. It is hard to understand the problem as it is presented now, and the missing parts will make it difficult to find your post for other people who have the same problem and google for a solution ...

Answer (score 1):

Internal network adapter does not have the ability to work monitor mode. Please use an USB wifi dongle that can do this.

Comment: That does'nt explain how I got the first few outputs. I could also use tools from the aircrack-ng suite without any major problems.

Comment: @JithinJ Nice one! The thing is aircrack can work with some drivers with broken activities. Maybe now you understand why !

Comment: Thank You. Also does this explain why bettercap does'nt work like it is supposed to on Rpi 4?

Comment: @JithinJ bettercap is something else. It is almost like ettercap but it has some extra features. Now that extra features part is the problem here.